# udev rule - missing /dev/by-label

Tags: udev

want to create an udev rule for my hdd, I want to match the hdd via disk label

which would require udev's `DEVLINKS` to include that `/dev/by-label` information

However, when testing:

```
udevadm test /block/sda

...

DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-path..../dev/disk/by-diskseq ..../dev/disk/by-id
```

I see that `/dev/by-label` is not present inside `DEVLINKS`

How can I tell udev to use the `/dev/by-label` information (so that I can later match it) ?

Thanks

ps: using linux 6.2, ubuntu 23.04

pps: the symlink is present in my filesystem. It's just not present inside udev's `DEVLINKS`.

Answer (score 0):

should be testing via

```
sudo udevadm test /dev/sda1 #use the partition (not /block/sda - which is the disk)
```

that one shows /dev/disk/by-label